# Select ID elements with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to extract divs having ids that match the following regex expression "gridxpxx", x is an integer, grid5p42 is an example. But I get an error. Here is my jquery code.

`$("div:regex(id, ^([1-9])p[1-9][1-9])$")`

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: remove the anchor `^` and try

Comment: Your regex implies the string should start with a digit. That won't match `grid`. And by *integer* you mean digit...? And why `1-9`, not `0-9` (or `\d`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Improved from
// http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
  var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
      validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
      attr = {
        method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
        property: jQuery.trim(matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,''))
      },
      regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), 'ig');
  return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
};


// DEMO
// P.S: Non-literal RegExp Tokens like \d (digits) need to be double-escaped like \\d
$("div:regex(id, ^grid\\d+p\\d+$)").css({color:"red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid4p8">grid4p8</div>
<div id="grid12p24">grid12p24</div>
<div id="gridfoobar">gridfoobar</div>
<div id="grid12p24foo">grid12p24foo</div>
<div id="grid4p32">grid4p32</div>
<div id="grid8p24">grid8p24</div>
```

**NOTE** The code is improved cause [in the *extension's* DOCS](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) the syntax highlighter (or directly from the server...) has eaten most of the script's backslashes... Also added a `$.trim` to allow spaces before the `attribute`'s comma.